# Disable sorting of a column when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

In the caption of a column of my boostrap table y have a button displaying a modal help.
The problem is that the column is sortable: then, when I click in the button both sorting and help displaying happens. 
How can I disable the sorting action in the button but not in the column text?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need to add your own code on the click event of the button. Use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the column's click event and after that, you need to show the modal using `$("your_modal_selector").modal('show');`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question:

```
$( "#helpButton_id" ).click(function( event ) {
      // stopPropagation prevents the further sorting to happen
      event.stopPropagation();
      // show the modal programatically
      $('#Modal_id').modal('show');
    });
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this solution is that the columns not shown originally (having `data-visible="false"` in the code of the webpage) doesn't have this behaviour when are shown.

Also, the help button are displayed in the column selector, which is not desirable.